# Unselect all elements from a Materialize multiple dropdown except first

Tags: javascript, jquery, material-design, multi-select

I have a multi-select drop down as following, where I have selected the multiple options.

```
  <select class="select2 mysql_attr" id="mysql_attr" name="mysql_attr[]" title="Student " multiple >
        <option value="0"> All</option>
        <option value="1">Sub 1</option>
        <option value="2">Sub 2</option>
        <option value="3">Sub 3</option>
        <option value="4">Sub 4</option>
    </select>
```

I have a first option called "All". When this option is clicked i want all selected items should be deselected except this and if other options click this option should be deselect.

I Search a lot but din't find anything.

How can I accomplish this using Materialize?

Comment: why cant you use check box instaed?